# ExitWindowsEx windows 7 shutdown does not work

Tags: winapi, windows-7

I am trying to get a Windows 7 machine to reboot from a C# WPF application. To this extent I've added the following code (I used an enum, but to keep the code short I'm just inserting the constants here):

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
static extern bool ExitWindowsEx(ExitWindows uFlags, ShutdownReason dwReason);

public static void Reboot() {
    ExitWindowsEx(0x02, 0x0)
}
```

On Windows 7 machines this does absolutely nothing (for me anyway). Changing the 0x2 (reboot) to 0x0 (logoff) does make the code logoff the current user, but the Reboot code doesn't seem to work.

Using the GetLastError API call didn't do much either. It just says something about the function having completed successfully.

For now I just cope by calling the shutdown command with /r /f, but I'd prefer to be able to call a Windows API directly from my application, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

You are not checking for errors correctly.  Only check if the function returns false, do *not* pinvoke GetLastError(), use Marshal.GetLastWin32Error() instead.  Best way:

```
public static void Reboot() {
    if (!ExitWindowsEx(0x02, 0x0)) {
        throw new System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception();
    }
}
```

With high odds that you'll find out that you don't have enough privileges to reboot the machine.  AdjustTokenPrivileges required, check the MSDN article.

Comment: I'll have a look at this when I get back to the office. I'm running the code under my own account information though, which is a domain admin. In addition I've now rewritten the Reboot() function to call the external shutdown.exe with the /r flag which does work (for the same user). A privilege issue would seem odd to me.